# EXC_BREAKPOINT error

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, crash

I'm getting an EXC_BREAKPOINT (EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT) error when trying to access/create and object in core data.

The code it errors on is the med= line below

```
    let instance = Singleton.sharedInstance
    NSLog("MOC: %@", instance.moc)
    var med : Medicine!
    med = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Medicine", inManagedObjectContext: instance.moc) as Medicine
```

i know the managed object context is fine as when i print it out i get

> MOC:

The core data files are kept in a separate framework

Comment: Any core data operations should be performed inside MOC.performBlock (or) MOC.performBlockAndWait()